# If user is not admin, deregister jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I really hope this is not a duplicate question. I'm beginning my journey into Wordpress theme development. I've been using the Codex as documentation to write each component I create. However, I have came across a snippet which for some reason I cannot get my head across it.

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', ( 'ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js' ), false, null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

Reading the snippet in pure English it says, if user is not admin, deregister jQuery, register it again, and queue it for output when the page is sent at the right time. Why would I want to do this when I can simply add jQuery to a set of '<script></script>' tags and be done with it?

**EDIT**

Should've mention where I discovered this snippet. I found it in the functions.php file on Blank Theme by http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/

Comment: Without more context there's no way we can possibly know why someone would do that.

Comment: Does WordPress ever make sense?

Comment: I don't understand this??? I have googled it for hours and read a couple of articles mention something about adding jQuery to the backend for admins but this wouldn't be that as it checks to see if user is not an admin.

Comment: You'll probably have more luck with an answer over at [WordPress Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/).

Comment: All this snippet does at this point is possibly cause certain plugins to not function. (scripts that were previously registered would now load before jquery was included.) If that really is the intent, this is a horrible way of accomplishing that.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that specific version of jQuery is needed for the admin *tools* for WP. Other parts of the actual public website might want more recent versions of jQuery, or no jQuery at all.

Comment: http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/loading-jquery-from-the-google-cdn-with-wp_register_script/ There is something about loading jQuery from Google CDN but it still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Blazemonger Huh? It checks if user is not an admin though... *(eg if( !is_admin() )*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[is_admin()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) checks if the current *page* being displayed is an admin Dashboard page. To check if the *user* is an admin, you'd use [current_user_can('administrator')](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) -- or, even better, check for a particular capability.

The purpose of this code is to leave the version of jQuery that comes with WordPress intact for admin pages (which use a lot of jQuery & AJAX) but load a different one on themed pages. They might have been trying to load a newer version than what shipped with WordPress at the time, or they could have just been trying to get it loaded off Google's CDN.

Answer (score 1):

This script loads a specific version of jquery, actually a pretty old one as version 1.10.2 is the current up-to-date version.

Probably it is used in a plugin where some javascript functions are broken in more recent versions of jquery.

If possible, try to avoid setting scripts directly in the head with script tags.
In this way it is possible to dynamic load/unload scripts (as you've demonstrated).

Comment: Yeah I seen how old it was and I was like, wut? Why use an older version of jQuery when I can use a new one if I want. Yes I guess that makes more sense. I cannot find much documentation on this snippet other than [here](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/loading-jquery-from-the-google-cdn-with-wp_register_script/), [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/linking-to-jquery-the-right-way), and [here](http://www.webinbangla.com/wp_deregister_script-wordpress/#.Ut1SHRAo6Uk) which are pretty much useless in ways of describing how the code is actually working.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is probably:

```
register_unminified_jquery();
if(!admin) {
    unregister();
    register_minified_jquery();
}
```

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js It's actually registering a minified version of jQuery. I should've mentioned but I found it this a theme called Blank Theme by http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/

Comment: @W3Geek: It's registering a minified version of jquery _for non admins_. Perhaps elsewhere it registers an unminified one

Comment: Oh lol I didn't even think about that. I looked all over for where it should be loading the non-minified version of jQuery and couldn't find anything.