# How to load a script only if it is not an admin?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a function to add a script to `wp_head()`, but i want this script to be loaded for any one but admin. So i have used the condition `if(!is_admin)` to achieve this. but it keeps loading for administrator. What modifications needed?
Here is the code i use :

```
function add_this_script_footer(){
    if(!is_admin()) :
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var message="My massage";
            function clickIE4(){
                if (event.button==2){
                    alert(message);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function clickNS4(e){
                if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
                   if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
                      alert(message);
                      return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (document.layers){
                document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
                document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
            } else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
                document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
            }

            document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
        </script>
    <?php 
    endif;
} 
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer');
```

Comment: To check if the user is an admin, you'd use current_user_can('administrator') -- or, even better, check for a particular capability. Is that this what you need? It is from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239226/if-user-is-not-admin-deregister-jquery)

Comment: Thank a lot the `!current_user_can('administrator')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a js file inside theme folder.

**Mycustomjs.js**

```
        var message="My massage";
        function clickIE4(){
            if (event.button==2){
                alert(message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        function clickNS4(e){
            if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
               if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
                  alert(message);
                  return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (document.layers){
            document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
            document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
        } else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
            document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
        }

        document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
```

**Add This code into function.php**

```
/*add js from template root folder*/

function my_custom_scripts() {
    if(!current_user_can('administrator')){
    wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/Mycustomjs.js', array('jquery'));
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts');
```